# Python convert MS Access "Date/Time Extended" / bytestring to readable string or datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, ms-access, milliseconds

I have an MS Access table with a field which has the date type "Date/Time Extended". It holds the value "4:00:00.0000000 PM". I retrieve this using pyodbc (drivers: 'SQL Server', 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server', 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)', 'Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)', 'Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)'):

```
    conn_str = r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=database.accdb'
    conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
    sql = "SELECT TradeTime FROM TradeTable"

    with conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)

        columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
        df = [tuple(row) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
        df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=columns)
    
    return df
```

When I retrieve this, I obtain a bytes object in the returned DataFrame looking like this: b'0000000000000693593:0000000576000000000:7\x00'.

How can I convert this back to a string, like "4:00:00.0000000 PM" or datetime object, so that I can work with it?

I tried .decode() and the struct library but didn't obtain any good results. All I know is that according to the [documentary](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-the-date-time-extended-data-type-708c32da-a052-4cc2-9850-9851042e0024)  the datetime is an "Encoded string of 42 bytes".

Comment: What driver did you use? How did you query the database and how did you get that buffer? It's the driver's job to return a proper datetime object. Date/Time Extended is *very* new. That article refers to Access 2021 and 365 only. If you use an older driver it won't be converted properly

Comment: I used pyodbc and have "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}" in the connection string. I have sent a simple SQL command like "SELECT TradeTime FROM TradeTable" and retrieved the data into a pandas DataFrame with cursor.fetchall(). Given I cannot get a proper dateime object from the driver, can't I convert that byte value somehow?

Comment: This is nontrivial. See https://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/162/Examine-how-DateTime2-type-stored-in-the-data-file.aspx for a SQL server example of how to go about it

Comment: @ErikA this isn't a SQL Server question or about the `datetime2` type. There's no reason to read the actual bytes either, all drivers return proper dates. This question is specifically about *Access*, a new type and what looks may be an old driver

Comment: @Paul post the code in the question itself. What's the driver version? You shouldn't have to convert anything

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The concept is the same, the steps to follow too. I've got a fair bit of experience with Access and good reason to believe they'll simply expose it as a binary field through ODBC without documentation (certainly wouldn't be the first time for Access), so you'll have to follow the same steps to determine the format and use it. The datetime/extended type essentially is the datetime2 type but for Access.

Comment: The types aren't the same. In SQL Server a `datetime2` value is 6-8 bytes depending on precision. This is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and the link you posted doesn't contradict this. The question's binary string is 42 bytes.

Comment: Your point being? The steps to follow (experiment, change different parts of the datetime field in the database and see how they are reflected in the output, then parse and interpret the field) is the same. The binary representation is not.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I posted my code in the question. Does anyone have an idea on how to proceed from here?